# How write regex for matches String and BigInteger in java?

Tags: java

I tried to use this site https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output. But I didn’t succeed.

My Java Regular Expression :

```
(.*)\\w+=[0-9][0-9]*$(.*)
```

Entry to test against :

```
a = 800000000000000000000000
```

My code needs to give `true` for `data.matches("(.*)\\w+=[0-9][0-9]*$(.*)")` of `a = 800000000000000000000000`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik I want my program to work like data.matches("(.*)\\w+=[0-9][0-9]*$(.*)") ==true

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash No, It don't work for .matches()

Comment: @plaza2009 - Please explain your [real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), rather than just your attempted solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testStrs = { "a = 800000000000000000000000", "a = ABC800000000000000000000000",
                "a = 800000000000000000000000ABC", "a = 12.45", "a = 800000000000ABC000000000000", "a = ABC",
                "a = 900000000000000000000000", "a = -800000000000000000000000", "a = -900000000000000000000000" };
        for (String str : testStrs) {
            System.out.println(
                    str + " -> " + (str.matches("[A-Za-z]\\s+=\\s+[-]?\\d+") ? " matches." : " does not match."));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a = 800000000000000000000000 ->  matches.
a = ABC800000000000000000000000 ->  does not match.
a = 800000000000000000000000ABC ->  does not match.
a = 12.45 ->  does not match.
a = 800000000000ABC000000000000 ->  does not match.
a = ABC ->  does not match.
a = 900000000000000000000000 ->  matches.
a = -800000000000000000000000 ->  matches.
a = -900000000000000000000000 ->  matches.
```

**Explanation:**

1. `[A-Za-z]` is for alphabets
2. `\\s+` is for space(s)
3. `[-]?` is for optional `-`
4. `\\d+` is for digits

Comment: NO, BigInteger is any number, 800000000000000000000000 or 900000000000000000000000 or something else

Comment: No, it isn't. What about negative numbers? The regex should be "[-]?\\d+"

Comment: it needs to match "a = 800000000000000000000000"

Comment: try recheck your regexp in this site https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: `it needs to match a = 800000000000000000000000` - *It should also match  `a = 900000000000000000000000` or `a = -800000000000000000000000` isn't it?*

Answer (score 0):

expanding on the previous answer and the comment from atmin (i can't post comments anywhere yet), you could exclude leading zeroes as well with:

```
String regex = "0|(\\-?[1-9]\\d*)";
String stringToTest = "..."
boolean result = stringToTest.matches(regex);
```

Comment: Are you seriously? instead of 800000000000000 there can be any number

Comment: yes, this works with any integer (no matter how big), but it does not match leading 0s (requires 1-9 as first digit) and no '-0'
just take the previous answer and replace the part after '=\\s+'; again, this is just an addition because i can't comment anywhere